# Magento avoid use custom customer attributes in forms

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a custom customer attribute. I have assign it to the forms using used_in_forms.

```
'used_in_forms' => array('adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_checkout','customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create', 'checkout_register'),
```

But now I do not want to use this attribute in forms. How can I remove above setting?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the install 
In `config.xml` add the  tag and changed version to for exp from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2.:

```
<global>
     <resources>
         <yourmod_customer_setup>
             <setup>
                 <module>YOURMOD_Customer</module>
             </setup>
         </yourmod_customer_setup>
     </resources>
    ...
</global>
```

create `YOURMOD\Customer\sql\yourmod_customer_setup\upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2.php` with

```
<?php

$this->startSetup();

Mage::getSingleton( 'eav/config' )
->getAttribute( 'customer', 'used_in_forms' )
->setData( 'used_in_forms', array( 'adminhtml_customer' ) ) // chages here 
->save();

$this->endSetup();
```

And very important as always: Clear your cache!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I need to avoid displaying in forms. But attribute should NOT delete.

Comment: that's exactly what the code in the answer does. It does not delete the attribute. It just updates the setting (used_in_forms) of your attribute

Comment: @KNKM as Raks mentioned in his comment it will just update your attribute it will not delete your existing attribute.You can check it on your dev environment

Answer (score 0):

you just need to remove attribute from database,  for that you can use following code.

```
<?php $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
      $custAttr = 'addattributecode_here'; 
      $setup->removeAttribute('customer', $custAttr);
      $setup->endSetup(); 
?>
```